# django - prevent duplicates for users

Tags: python, django

Here is the Model class

```
class Album(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    public = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    user = models.ForeignKey(get_user_model())

    class Meta:
        unique_together = (("name", "user"),)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('photos:index')
```

Here is the View

```
class Create(CreateView):
    model = Album
    fields = ['name', 'public']
    form_class = AlbumCreateForm

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.user = self.request.user
        return super(Create, self).form_valid(form)
```

And here is the form Class

```
class AlbumCreateForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Album
        fields = ['name', 'public']
        labels = {'name': '', 'public': 'Public'}

    def __init__(self,*args, **kwargs):
        super(AlbumCreateForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['name'].widget = forms.TextInput(
            attrs={'placeholder': 'name'})
```

I can create album just fine, but what I would like to do is prevent duplicate albums from being created for a particular user. For example if user1 has already created album1, he should not be able to create another album named album1.

The place where I can do it is AlbumCreateForm. But AlbumCreateForm does not have any knowledge of current user. Any idea how it can be accomplished?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Pass user to form - add him to form kwargs by adding this method to view:

   ```
   def get_form_kwargs(self, *args, **kwargs):
       kwargs = super(Create, self).get_form_kwargs(*args, **kwargs)
       kwargs['user'] = self.request.user
       return kwargs
   ```
2. Get user in form and check:

   ```
   def __init__(self,*args, **kwargs):
       self.user = kwargs.pop('user') # this line added
       super(AlbumCreateForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
       self.fields['name'].widget = forms.TextInput(
          attrs={'placeholder': 'name'})

   def clean(self):
       if Album.objects.filter(user=self.user).exists():
           raise forms.ValidationError('Error description')
   ```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I got it working not. Two things though. 1. Your filter needs additional rule. 2. If I use the clean method I get the following error http://dpaste.com/0Y80BWQ/. But if I put the same code in clean_name(self): it works fine. :-|